# Cannot enter long commands in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, putty

I am using putty (0.64.0.0 2015) to access the terminal on an AIX server. Normally typing long commands works just fine but somehow something weird happened and when I type long commands Linux cursor goes back on the same line even behind the 'bash' word.

In order to explain the problem I have a picture. Just to explain in the picture I start with capital 'ABC' then '1-10' and then small 'abc' and then repeat this sequence to simulate a long command.

[image: Trying to write a long command]

Can anybody please explain why this is happening (it has also happened before) and how to solve it without restarting putty? Does it have to do with a buffer of some kind since the command runs just fine it is only that it looks like this in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your shell is no longer aware of its terminal's dimensions. Perhaps you've resized the PuTTY window after logging in?

Sometimes `resize` will fix such issues.

Comment: You are right it was the problem but why does it go on the same line, if putty is not Aware of the dimensions then why not writing the code just on the next line?

Comment: If it thought it was the wrong size it would go to the next line not wrap around.

Comment: @123 changing the dimension (making the screen small again) seems to get rid of the problem.

Comment: I've seen wrapping not go to next line, @123. I believe whether wrap goes to same line or next will depend on what the shell believes its terminal capabilities (`termcap`) are.

Comment: Yes, OP should do this (in the shell): `eval $(resize -s)`